# How to verify if a public key is a PDA without the seeds?

Tags: solana-program, pda, rust

If we have a public key, how can we determine if it is a PDA? Especially in the case where we don't have any information about the source code programs related to the public key. Is it possible to check this on-chain?

Answer (score 4):

Just found the solution.

Use [is_on_curve method](https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/src/solana_program/pubkey.rs.html#610-612) of PublicKey. It tries to decompress from the curve 25519 using [bytes_are_curve_point](https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/src/solana_program/pubkey.rs.html#142), which is a requirement of program derived addresses.

Comment: while this is _generally_ accurate, it should be noted that there is a legacy address derivation scheme (the so-called `*WithSeed` system instruction variants) that did not strictly force their outputs off-curve and _may_ produce addresses on-or-off curve